# Verify SSL/TLS version being used for XMPPFramework iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, xmpp, xmppframework

I've been hunting for this information for a while, and I may be looking in all the wrong places.

I'm using XMPPFramework for iOS, and we have a requirement (sadly) to allow TLS1.0 connections from our client to our xmpp ejabberd server.

Is there a way I can verify what version of TLS I'm authenticating with?

I know that a secure connection is being made, because the xmppStreamDidSecure delegate is called.

I have set the required property in info.plist to limit the TLS auth to 1.0. However, I don't know if that effects the xmppframework library or not? I would assume that the entire app would be limited by whatever is set there.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<false/>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>xxx.xxx.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.0</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a packet sniffer/proxy tool such as [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/), especially if it's a third-party library that's initiating the request.  However, even if it was your own code that was initiating the authentication, I'm pretty sure that Apple's frameworks handles the actual nuts-and-bolts transactions, so you're not going to get much visibility at the code level (you **might** be able to find out more specifics by bridging to CFNetworking, but that's a hail-mary).

As a side note, you should probably use `NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion` instead; the "temporary" keys were for early iOS 9 beta versions:  http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/.  Also, since that's documented as a **minimum** version, there's no guarantee that the framework library **won't** try and use a version **greater** than that.